# Is "initial Partial Fragment" of Lists a Comonad?

Tags: category-theory, monads

Lists can be captured as Monads, where the product axiom is given as concatenation.  Given a list $l = Concat(l_1, l_2)$, where $Concat$ is the concatenation of two lists, we say that $l_1$ is an initial partial fragment of $l$.  For any list $l$, there is a list of lists of initial partial fragments.  For example, let $P : List \rightarrow List \cdot List$ be a natural transformation that takes the $List$ functor to its composition with itself.

$$P : [a,b,c] \rightarrow [[a], [a,b]]$$

Does this convert the List monad into a bimonad, where P is the coproduct natural transformation?

I think the problem is that I cannot imagine a counit.  Perhaps a good counit is the following:

$$\eta : [l_1,l_2,l_3] \rightarrow l_3$$

ie, it picks out the last element.

Note:
It has been pointed out that you cannot have a counit because there is no map on the empty list.  To resolve this, I want to use the non-empty list monad [that is mentioned in this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/237692/list-is-a-monad-but-is-it-a-comonad-with-these-natural-transformations)

Comment: What happens on the empty list?

Comment: @DanDoel Hi, I'm not sure.  A list of two empty lists?  I have heard this before.  This may have to all be applied to streams or non-empty lists.  Could you give some hints or feel free to answer the question by making any necessary changes.

Comment: Looks like you found the answer. :) Note that it's important for $P$ to keep the entire list as one of the elements.